# Slider does not change values In Blazor

Tags: blazor, slider, blazor-server-side, slideshow, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to get a slider in Blazor to the budget parameter, but when one moves the slider then the budget value doesn't change. Why is that, and how could I fix it?

Here is the [component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFcqm.png)
I'm using the IJSRuntime to use js fonctions,
and here [what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB46w.png).

Comment: You can't pass Func to IJSRuntime InvokeAsync method. If you want to trigger C# method from JS - you have to use a DotNetObjectRef and then invoke methods on it. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Please don't screenshoot code. Instead copy and paste it. And format it properly. That makes things much more convenient and people will more likely be ready to help you. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered simplifying it to something like this.  No JS, no hoops : you are using Blazor, not a JS framework.  You can apply whatever CSS framework you want to polish it.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div>
    <label>Daily Budget</label>
    <input class="mx-3" type="range" min="@_min" max="@_max" @bind=_budget @bind:event="oninput"/>
    <span class="ms-4">$@_budget:00</span>
</div>

@code{
    private int _min = 0;
    private int _max = 1000;
    private int _budget;
}
```

[image]